# How to set DisableCNCheck using Spring Integration jax-wS implementation

Tags: soap, cxf, spring-integration, spring-ws

What is Spring Integration equivalent of `TLSClientParameters.setDisableCNCheck(true)` in cxf

Can we set `DisableCNCheck` in `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` or in `org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapHeader`?

Below Soap request is captured with TCP monitor,  on running sample cxf client with  params.setDisableCNCheck(true):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: Apache CXF 2.6.2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 243

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>...</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

DisableCNCheck is not set to SOAP header. It probably set to http header.

Comment: Can you show how it looks from Soap Header perspective? At least as XML

Comment: I have added SOAP header in the question. DisableCNCheck probably is getting added to http header.

Comment: I'd say it is a `server` option for SSL connection to prevent client certificate validation. Really not sure how to configure it without CXF